# How to automate solr indexing?

Tags: solr

Normally we do indexing in solr from a browser. Can we do it automatically by writing a batch job or java code?

Please provide me some idea, if it is possible.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is the source and frequency of update etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataImportHandler, which can import from lot of different sources such as databases or xml files: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

If you have specific requirements which are not satisfied by the DataImportHandler you may implement your own indexer by using a solr client api:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Client+APIs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do stuff with Solr programmaticaly take a look at: [Solrj](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ) which is an API that'll do what your asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web debugging proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view the HTTP request that is generated when you trigger the data import via a web browser.  Then send the same request from your Java code.